# How do I render partial from another controller with collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a dashboard controller that has an action of an online_user. In the view, under dashboard, I have a partial _online_user.html.haml. In it, I am trying to display online logged in users. Here the code:

```
 app/controllers/dashboard_controller 
  class DashboardController < ApplicationController
      def online_user
        @online_users = Profile.all(...)
     end
    end

app/views/dashboard/_online_user.html.haml


%li
  = link_to profile_path(online_user) do
    = online_user.name
    %i.icon-picture
    %i.icon-th-large
    %i.icon-camera
    %i.icon-facetime-video
    %span.help-block
      = online_user.try(:age) 
      - 
      = online_user.state.try(:name)
      ,
      = online_user.country.try(:name)
```

With all this in place, the last thing is to render this in another view. Right? Like so:

```
= render partial: "dashboard/online_user", collection: @online_users
```

However, when I do this, I get a blank page. Nothing is being rendered. Anyone's thoughts much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether @online_users contains anything, and isn't empty?
Furthermore, this might help:

```
= render partial: "dashboard/online_user", collection: @online_users, as: :online_user
```

Comment: Thanks @ARjan. Indeed, I did check for collection whether or not it's empty. Your code example is good but it's not working for me in this case.